# Is there an Emacs variable to turn off backup of files with a specific extension?

Tags: emacs, backup, elisp

For example when editing various data files, the backup data is no use and actually trips up our tools. So I'd like to be able to disable backup for files containing a regexp in the name.

justinhj

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I hate to simply reference other online resources for questions like these, but this appears to be a perfect fit for your needs.

http://anirudhs.chaosnet.org/blog/2005.01.21.html

Once you've setup what's described on that page, you could just add this to your `.emacs` or `.emacs.d/init.el` file depending on your version of emacs:

```
(setq auto-mode-alist (append '(("\\.ext1$" . sensitive-mode)) auto-mode-alist))
(setq auto-mode-alist (append '(("\\.ext2$" . sensitive-mode)) auto-mode-alist))
(setq auto-mode-alist (append '(("\\.ext3$" . sensitive-mode)) auto-mode-alist))
(setq auto-mode-alist (append '(("\\.ext4$" . sensitive-mode)) auto-mode-alist))
```

Where `\\.ext1$`, `\\.ext2$`, etc. are the regular expressions that match the filenames you don't want backups for.

Comment: But of course, you lose the usual functionality of the auto-mode-alist when you set it up this way.  I would just (add-hook 'some-mode-hook #'sensitive-mode) to the modes that you don't want backups for.

Comment: Thanks Sean, that's working out well.

jrockway: I'm not sure of the implications of what I'm losing. I guess you mean that sensitive-mode becomes the only mode for those files? I can't have .obj files opened in c or html mode for example?

Comment: @justinhj the `sensitive-mode` according to the blog post in the answer is defined as _minor-mode_ therefore would allow you to open C or HTML files in their appropriate _major-mode_ without conflict.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use the built-in Emacs functionality do something like this:

```
(defvar my-backup-ignore-regexps (list "foo.*" "\\.bar$")
  "*List of filename regexps to not backup")

(defun my-backup-enable-p (name)
  "Filter certain file backups"
  (when (normal-backup-enable-predicate name)
    (let ((backup t))
      (mapc (lambda (re)
              (setq backup (and backup (not (string-match re name)))))
            my-backup-ignore-regexps)
      backup)))

(setq backup-enable-predicate 'my-backup-enable-p)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could always ask emacs to put the backup/autosave files in your home dir.

http://amitp.blogspot.com/2007/03/emacs-move-autosave-and-backup-files.html

```
(defvar user-temporary-file-directory
  (concat temporary-file-directory user-login-name "/"))
(make-directory user-temporary-file-directory t)
(setq backup-by-copying t)
(setq backup-directory-alist
      `(("." . ,user-temporary-file-directory)
        (,tramp-file-name-regexp nil)))
(setq auto-save-list-file-prefix
      (concat user-temporary-file-directory ".auto-saves-"))
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
      `((".*" ,user-temporary-file-directory t)))
```